# How to fix signatures hidclass.sys , hidparse.sys , hidusb.sys in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, bsod

Blue screen - 0x000021a
Windows boots when disabling mandatory driver signing. sigverif.exe showed hidclass.sys , hidparse.sys , hidusb.sys not signed. And now also basicdisplay.sys , basicrender.sys .

sfc /scannow - did not give results

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source: - also to no avail

there are no recovery points, I just tried to download and replace these files. After that, windows stopped running at all, even without driver signatures, and eventually returned the old ones.

the branch center does not update

Comment: Strip `/source`, so it uses the Windows Update Service to check against.

Comment: "hid" stands for Human Device Interface, and it involves devices like mice, keyboards, removable devices, printers etc. Why have you installed an unsigned driver for such a device? Not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the branch manually. Downloaded the exe installer of the branch from https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/software-download/windows10 I made the installation from under the mode with disabled signatures and everything worked fine, there is no error.